# Why is my ResultSet empty when I get it from PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()?

Tags: java, mysql

First things first, the snippet. Some strings are in my native language, but it shouldn't matter much:

```java
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ADDR)) {
            String randomCode = user.substring(0, Math.min(6, user.length()));


            /* 

            SOME VALIDATION CODE THAT SHOULDN'T MATTER HERE, I TESTED THIS AND
            IT WORKS FINE, AND CAN BE REMOVED SAFELY WITH THE SAME ISSUE PERSISTING.
            IT JUST CHANGES THE randomCode VARIABLE TO SOMETHING UNIQUE.

            */

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO utenti(utente_nome, utente_codice) VALUES(?,?);", new String[] {"utenti.utente_id", "utenti.utente_attivo", "utenti.utente_compilazione"});
            stmt.setString(1, user);
            stmt.setString(2, randomCode);
            int amt = stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(amt); //This prints "1", the row is actually inserted in the database, with all the generated fields looking fine.
            if (amt > 0) {
                ResultSet user_data_set = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
                if (user_data_set.next()) {
                    return User.fromResultSet(user_data_set); //user_data_set has no columns
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("L'utente appena creato non è stato resitituito dal server.");
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("L'utente appena creato non è stato resitituito dal server. (2)");
            }
        }
```

I'm adding records to a table on a mysql database I set up on a different machine, and after I add one I need to access to the automatically generated fields, to have an abstraction of the database objects in my program.

My problem: the ResultSet I use in the line with the return instruction is empty. I'm sure the statement is executed correctly, things pop up just fine in the database (including the generated keys), and the `User.fromResultSet()` method is currently just a stub that prints the contents to console.

**I've already looked at the other similar questions**, and I've already tried:

- Replacing the string array with `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`
- Removing the string array
- Having only one String in the array
- Using numeric indexes for my columns, replacing the array with an `int[]`

Anyone that can point me in the right direction? I've been on this for an inhuman amount of time.

Comment: You never commit that transaction. If  your transaction isolation level is `Repeatable Read` or even `Serializable` you will never get that until it's commited to avoid non-repeatable read phenomena. Just call `conn.commit()` after stmt.executeUpdate().
To read more information about transaction isolation levels take a look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transaction-isolation-levels-dbms/

Comment: Post the relevant code. We have no idea of what User.fromResultSet() precisely does, of what the output you expect is, and of what the actual output is. We also don't know how the table is defined.

Comment: As I explained in the post, the method just calls System.out.println. The expected results and what gets printed to stdout is explained next to the relevant lines in comments